# A technical relation

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I have encountered the following interesting technical relation.

$$ \pi^2 = \inf_{x \in \mathcal{D}(0,1) \setminus\{0\}} \frac{\int_0^1 |x'(s)|^2 \, \text{d}s}{\int_0^1 |x(s)|^2 \, \text{d}s}$$

where $\mathcal{D}(0,1)$ is the set of all smooth functions in $(0,1)$ with a compact support.

Amazing. Can anyone please give a hint why this is true? Thank you.

Comment: When you say "encountered," what do you mean?

Comment: That should be inf instead of sup.

Comment: Note, you can restrict the problem to when $\int_0^1 |x(s)|^2ds=1$. That also elminates the case $x(s)=0$ for all $s$...

Comment: @John Thanks for your reminder.

Comment: If you want to, I can write an answer, but do you just want a hint?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews You are right. Sorry I just jotted this down very roughly and informally. This makes the question I posed full of mistakes.

Comment: @John I am happy with both. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, we write down the fourier expansion of $x(t)$:

$$x(t) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \sin(n\pi t) + \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n \cos (n\pi t)$$

(the main point is that $x(t)$ has no constant term, do you know why?). Thus

$$\int_0^1 |x(t)|^2 dt = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^2 + b_n^2$$

and

$$\int_0^1 |x'(t)|^2 dt = \pi ^2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2(a_n^2 + b_n^2)$$

$$\Rightarrow \frac{\int_0^1|x'(t)|^2 dt}{\int_0^1 |x(t)|^2 dt} =  \frac{\pi^2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2 (a^2_n + b_n^2)}{ \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^2 + b_n^2} \geq \pi^2\frac{\sum_{n=1}^\infty a^2_n + b_n^2}{\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^2 + b_n^2} = \pi^2 $$

With equality as $f(t)= \sin(\pi t)$. (Strictly speaking the infimum is not attained as this function does not have compact support).

Comment: That first equality on the last line is totally wrong.  $\frac{a+b}{c+d}\neq \frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{d}$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Thanks, let me fix that.

Comment: You've still got the fraction error in the last line, only on the inequality step, and you also lost the square from $\pi^2$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Sorry, my bad.

Comment: Thanks! I had been thinking about this for several hours but failed to figure out it is done simply by Fourier series expansion.

Comment: @CheungSW: You are welcome! Indeed, it's just a start of a big question: instead of $(0,1)$, you consider a open set $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ and ask for the infimum of $\frac{\int_\Omega |\nabla f|^2 dx}{\int_\Omega |f|^2 dx}$. In this case the infimum is related to the Laplace equation.

Comment: @John This question sounds more relevant to PDE than to functional analysis then. This is indeed the energy minimizer of the Laplace equation.

Answer (score 3):

I can prove that if $\pi^2$ is a lower bound then it must be the greatest one. Simply consider uniform approximations of $x(s)=\sin(\pi s)$ by functions with compact support. Then $x'$ will be approximated in the sense of $L^2$ and so you recover the result. I am not sure why $\pi^2$ is a lower bound, however.

Comment: I am sorry I made a mistake in posing the question.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is very useful indeed.